# How to fix 0o prefix, especially in date = datetime(2021,07,31) as an input to find day of week in a function?

Tags: python

```
def day_of_week(date):
    import datetime
    return datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%A')

date = datetime(2021,07,31)
print(day_of_week(date))
```

Output:

```
File "<ipython-input-12-3ae733ff3245>", line 5
    date = datetime(2021,07,31)
                          ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; 
               use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

Comment: By removing 0 from 7 the following is the output: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-110fe5e073b0> in <module>
      3     return datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%A')
      4 
----> 5 date = datetime(2021,7,31)
      6 print(day_of_week(date))

NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: You only `import datetime` inside the function. You need to do that outside if you want to use `datetime` outside the function. Plus, you're trying to use the `datetime.datetime` class there, not the `datetime` module.

Comment: @Monica, if put `import datetime` outside the function and use `datetime` module then I am getting the follwing error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-df9f76c82410> in <module>
      5     return datetime.strftime(date, '%A')
      6 
----> 7 date = datetime(2021,7,31)
      8 print(day_of_week(date))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: You need to write `datetime.datetime(2021,7,31)`, not `datetime(2021,7,31)`.

Comment: @Monica, perfect now my code is working. Thanks a lot

Comment: @martineau, Thanks for editing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is that Python 3.0 and later doesn't like integer literals that start with zero and consist only of digits --- specifically, it's complaining about the 07 integer literal.

The reason this is a problem is that using a 0 prefix on an integer literal used to, especially in the Unix tradition, indicate a number that's supposed to be interpreted in octal (base-8) instead of decimal (base-10). For example, the Unix command `chmod` takes an octal value to set the flags for a file (e.g. `chmod 0753 foo.txt`). In Python you used to be able to do this same thing, but then it's ambiguous how to interpret an integer literal starting with 0.

So to avoid the ambiguity, if you really want to specify an integer literal using octal notation, starting in Python 3 you must prefix the octal literal with `0o` (that's a zero and a lower-case letter o). Similarly, you can also specify other bases like `0x` (hexadecimal, base-16), or `0b` (binary, base-2).

```
>>> 58 == 0x3a == 0o72 == 0b111010
True
```

For your case specifically, you probably want `datetime(2021, 7, 31)` but you could also spell this as `datetime(2021, 0o7, 31)`.

More information at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/

Comment: Although your explanation is largely correct, you don't really answer the original question.  You explained WHY it happened, but he doesn't actually want octal here.  The solution to his problem is to change the "07" to "7".

Comment: @Imjohns3, I really appreciate your answer, could you please help me here in my case by writing a line of code how could we use 0o in my problem to fix it, Thanks

Comment: @TimRoberts, Thanks. I have removed 0 from 7 already then I am getting the type error :  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c64b7964b5ad> in <module>
      4     return datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%A')
      5 
----> 6 date = datetime(2021,7,31)
      7 print(day_of_week(date))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Thanks to all of you, my code is working by using `datetime.datetime(2021,7,31)` instead of `datetime(2021,07,31)`

Answer (score 0):

Given your original zero-padded date, the following works for Python 3 without input string manipulation:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def day_of_week(date):
    return datetime.strftime(date, '%A')

date = datetime.strptime('2021,07,31', '%Y,%m,%d')
print(day_of_week(date))
```

It could alternatively be written as:

```py
def day_of_week(date):
    from datetime import datetime
    day = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y,%m,%d')
    return datetime.strftime(day, '%A')

print(day_of_week('2021,07,31'))
```